# jQuery AJAX status “200 OK”, but no data response, getting into error

Tags: jquery, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

i am trying to get access token from authorization code received by oauth2 redirect ui

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url:searchurl,
        data: {code:code, client_id:'clientid', client_secret:'secret', redirect_uri:'http://localhost:8085/mypro/getAccesstoken.jsp', grant_type:'authorization_code'},
        type:"POST",
        contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain:true,
        cache : true, 
        success:function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception, errorstr) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            alert(errorstr);
        }
    });
```

The url get 200 OK response but i am not getting response at all

[image]

Error on console:

```
Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error", more...}
```

when i tried to set request header Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

```
beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');},
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-He...    access-control-allow-origin
Access-Control-Request-Me...    POST
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Host    accounts.google.com
Origin  http://localhost:8085
Pragma  no-cache
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
```

i get error

```
"NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
```

Comment: what is the response text

Comment: @ArunPJohny Likely a cross-domain restriction: `readyState=0/status=0` (if it was *actually* getting a server response it'd be `readyState=4/status=5xx` or so).

Comment: response text is blank..

Comment: how to avoid cross domain restriction? i am working on localhost.

Comment: use jsonp. instead of json.

Comment: @AhmadF when i use jsonp i get 405 Method not allowed response

Comment: "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?callback=jQuery1830344730120744301_1385627060297&code=4%2F3zOMYXB4V91R74E6MMN1ldhl4-k3.Utq6c1XzufEVXE-sT2ZLcbRjxqE7hQI&client_id=clientid&client_secret=secret&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8085%2Fmypro%2FgetAccestoken.jsp&grant_type=authorization_code"

Comment: i no nothing of google-outh but consider changing request type to get.

Comment: @AhmadF Google-oauth2 allows only POST